# Unable to call common numpy functions in pydrake constraints

Tags: python, numpy, drake

I am working with an example in pydrake that has a constraint with polar coordinates that includes evaluating the following function:

```
def f(x):
    r = np.sqrt(x[0]**2 + x[1]**2)
    theta = np.arctan(x[1] / x[0])
    return np.array([r, theta])
```

However, it chokes on the `np.arctan` call with this error:

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type pydrake.autodiffutils.AutoD
> iffXd which has no callable arctan method

Is there an `atan` function in pydrake somewhere suitable for autodiff?

I have seen this error in other places and have just had to re-implement things myself (e.g. I tried `np.linalg.cholesky` and got a similar error so I implemented my own `cholesky` function using more basic operations). Are there better ways to work around this such that I can better utilize things in numpy with the pydrake autodiff?

#### UPDATE

It turns out you can use `np.arctan2(x[1], x[0])` and it works with pydrake autodiff, so I suppose that solves my specific problem. But I'm still curious to know how to work around these errors as they come up aside from implementing my own versions of them.

Comment: Numpy functions like `np.arctan` expect a `numpy` array or an object than can be turned into one.  But if the resulting array `dtype` is object (as opposed to a numeric dtype) it will try to delegate the action to a method of the array elements.  But almost no one implements `arctan` as a method.  You could check what `np.array(x[1] / x[0])` produces.  But I don't know why the `np.sqrt` and `np.arctan2` work, unless `np.array(x[0]` etc is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with Drake/PyDrake, any autodiffing program requires functions be implemented in a way that their derivatives are known.  It seems that PyDrake is inspecting your code, identifying functions it knows autodiff versions of (e.g., `np.arctan2`) and replacing them with those versions.  It looks like [this](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.math.html) is the list of functions PyDrake has implemented, so you may want to refer to this list rather than use trial and error.  Oddly enough, `arctan` is there as well as `arctan2`.  I think there may be an additional problem here, specifically that `arctan(y/x)` is not differentiable everywhere, whereas `arctan2(x, y)` is designed to fix that.  See these plots of [arctan(y/x)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20arctan%28y%2Fx%29) and [arctan2(x, y)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20arctan2%28x%2C%20y%29) as examples.

Regardless, for mathematical reasons you probably want to be using `arctan2` to find that angle, unless you know it's restricted to a certain range.

Comment: I agree with both points made here.  1) `pydrake` provides overloads for `sin`, `cos`, etc that support `double`, `AutoDiffXd`, and even our (symbolic) `Expression`.  2) `arctan2` sounds like the one you want here.